# Handling events in box-api with java

Tags: java, box-api

I´m newbie in box-api and i'm interesting in handling events with the new version of box java sdk. I've read the documentation about events and i have only found the following code.

I will be gratefull if anyone can help me with code, for example, handling a event of an upload of a file.

```
    BoxAPIConnection api = new BoxAPIConnection("YOUR-DEVELOPER-TOKEN");
    EventStream stream = new EventStream(api);
    stream.addListener(new EventListener() {
        public void onEvent(BoxEvent event) {
            // Handle the event.
            ???? Need help here ????
        }
    });
    stream.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with your `EventListener`. In your `onEvent(BoxEvent)` method, you'll first want to filter on the type of events you're interested in with something like:

```
if (event.getType() == BoxEvent.Type.ITEM_UPLOAD) {
    // Do something
}
```

You can also find a full list of the supported event types [in the javadocs](http://opensource.box.com/box-java-sdk/javadoc/com/box/sdk/BoxEvent.Type.html).

Once you know the event type, you can cast the event source to the appropriate type. For example, if we're handling a `BoxEvent.Type.ITEM_UPLOAD` event, then the event source would be a `BoxItem`.

```
if (event.getType() == BoxEvent.Type.ITEM_UPLOAD) {
    BoxItem uploadedItem = (BoxItem) event.getSource();

    // Do something with the uploaded item. For this example, we'll just print
    // out its name.
    BoxItem.Info itemInfo = uploadedItem.getInfo();
    System.out.format("A file named '%s' was uploaded.\n", itemInfo.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have list of events: https://developers.box.com/docs/

So where you have ??? in your code try

```
if(event == ITEM_UPLOAD) 
{
 //your action
}


or 

if(event == "ITEM_UPLOAD") 
{
{
 //your action
}
}
```

or this is probably correct:

```
if(event.type == "ITEM_UPLOAD") 
    {
     //your action
    }
```

And to see what event you are getting write this inside onEvent():

```
System.out.println("Event: " + event);
```

Comment: Sorry but you example not work, the solution is event.getType(). I want to work the event response with event.getSorce() and event.parseJsonMember(member) but I don't know how to do it.